# Size limitiations when "Linking within a multi-page document" with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

[Link to article](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-links.html)

> A single HTML document can contain one or many 'page' containers
>   simply by stacking multiple divs with a data-role of "page". This
>   allows you to build a small site or application within a single HTML
>   document; jQuery Mobile will simply display the first 'page' it finds
>   in the source order when the page loads.

I'm wondering about the limitations of this.
I'm building a site for a gallery exhibition which contains 340 images and 19 media files (audio and video)

The exhibition is divided into 16 seaprate galleries, each containing anythign from 4 to 90 images each.

Is this method descibed by jQuery mobile possible?

Obviously i'll be keeping the image size reasonable for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't built anything that large even in my demo time playing with jqm, but if you start to see your entire page document being more than say a 1MB in total size with images, html, css etc you are going run into some longer than recommended load times. I recommend checking this with google speed tools - It will give you a nice graph of all your resources loaded and the total page size (you will need to be on the dev channel of google chrome to use this tool)

I'm curious to see how usable this ends up. Let us know. If you do run into issues you may just have to find some logical points to split your document or possibly look at using json & flickr api to load some of your image galleries.